# Attribute Routing Strange Behavior in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I'm using attribute routing to specify my routes in a controller that inherits from System.Web.Http.ApiController. I'm getting some funky behavior. Here's some sample code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/1/user")]
public class UserRestController : ApiController
{
    UserService userService = new UserService();

    [Route("{id}"), HttpGet]
    public UserDTO Get(string id)
    {
        var user = userService.GetUserById(id);

        return user;
    }
}
```

That works absolutely how I would expect. When I visit ~/api/1/user/someId I get the expected information back. When I switch to not include the '1' in the route prefix I get "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'baseUrl/api/user/someId'."

I have mvc routes, web api routes and attribute routes all being registered on app start in this project but I would think that the default routes for this controller would be ~/userrest/... so I wouldn't think registering those would be the cause of this but I could be wrong.

Sample of what I want:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserRestController : ApiController
{
    UserService userService = new UserService();

    [Route("{id}"), HttpGet]
    public UserDTO Get(string id)
    {
        var user = userService.GetUserById(id);

        return user;
    }
}
```

I'd expect that ~/api/user/someId would work however I get the error mentioned above ("No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'baseUrl/api/user/someId'.").

Full error xml:

```
<Error> 
    <Message> 
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI     
        'baseUrl/api/user/someId';. 
    </Message> 
    <MessageDetail> 
        No type was found that matches the controller named 'user'. 
    </MessageDetail> 
</Error>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Sounds like it's working as expected.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand what you're saying now. You need to share your routes. Just because no route has 'userrest' in its path explicitly doesn't mean it's not being picked up by a matching URL segment.

Comment: I updated the question to show what I want to do. Hopefully that clears things up a little. Basically I want to be able to hit ~/api/user/someId but what I have in the second snippet of code is returning the error I had above. Here is the full xml returned:
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://baseUrl/api/user/someId'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'user'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
I have a feeling that the problem has to do with web api's routing but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you share how your Global.asax looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error description, you seem to have registered conventional routes before calling MapHttpAttributeRoutes. For example, you might be having a route like `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}"...)`. In this case the request like `api/user/someid` would match this route and the Web API would be looking for a controller of type `UserController`. Make sure to call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` before this conventional route.

*Basic rule*: more specific routes should be registered before less-specific or generic routes.